# Error: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'EditText.getText()' on a null object reference" even though objects are already instantiated

Tags: java, android, xml

I have found loads of posts dealing with the same error but they all seem to be due to people forgetting to instantiate one of their views before accessing it. As far as I can see that is not the case here.

This is my code:

```
public class EditExpense extends Activity {

Expense expense = new Expense();

// Fields from the view
EditText dateEditText;
EditText amountEditText;
EditText descriptionEditText;
EditText currencyEditText;
EditText categoryEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Instantiate the input fields.
    dateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_edit_text);
    amountEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount_edit_text);
    descriptionEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.desc_edit_text);
    currencyEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.currency_edit_text);
    categoryEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.category_edit_text);

    // This causes the error.
    String text = amountEditText.getText().toString();

    // Custom title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_expense);
    this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar_edit_expense);

    // Getting the photo
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bitmap photoBitmap = intent.getParcelableExtra(ExpenseList.TAKEN_PHOTO_KEY);
    expense.image = photoBitmap;
}
```

I previously got it working and I'm not sure what suddently made the code not work. I suspect it has something to do with the DatePicker fragment i recently implemented. This is the complete code if anyone is interested:

[EditExpense.java](http://pastebin.com/H26qvHbs)

[activity_edit_expense.XML](http://pastebin.com/VM3D4HvJ)

Comment: Move `setContentView()` right after your `super()` call.

Comment: @codeMagic awesome! Thanks man! :D